# Gitolite refuses to accept commits to gitolite-admin.git

Tags: gitolite

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gitolite-to-control-access-to-a-git-server-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) tutorial to install a gitolite server on my Debian PC. Once that works, I intend to connect to it from a virtual machine, to simulate client connection.

```
$ cd ~/ssh
$ ssh-keygen glite
$ sudo apt-get install gitolite3
$ export GL_LIBDIR=/home/default/bin/lib
$ export GL_BINDIR=/home/default/bin
$ gitolite setup -pk /home/default/.ssh/glite.pub
$ cd ~/projects
$ git clone ../repositories/gitolite-admin.git
#  make some changes
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 413 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: WARNING: Use of uninitialized value $repo in concatenation (.) or string at /home/default/bin/lib/Gitolite/Conf/Load.pm line 251, <DATA> line 1.
remote: 
remote: FATAL: invalid repo ''
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To ../../repositories/gitolite-admin.git/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '../../repositories/gitolite-admin.git/'
```

So some variable `$repo` is empty inside some python script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your local user has only read-persission ?
check the entry in your

```
../repositories/gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf
```

there should be an entry coresponding to your glite.pub file name in keydir.

```
repo    gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   glite
```